# Div text replace in other div

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want class="hotelname" echo text in class="a" and class="hotelname" is hide. is that possible? I used jQuery code but its not working.

```
<form id="" class="" method="GET" action="http://localhost/blue_bucket/county/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2 class="a"></h2>
    <?php
    foreach ($query as $row) 
    {   
        ?>
        <h3 class="hotelname"><?php echo $hotelnames =  $row->hotel; ?></h3>

        <div class="book-it-btn">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
        </div>
    </form>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery(".a").append(jQuery(".hotelname").html());
```

Comment: Question in not well specified. Be more specific what you want. I'm unable to understand your question.

Comment: you will get multiple class

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want `.hotelname` class value to put in `.a` class then you want to hide `.hotelname` class element ?

Check the working snippet below

> ```
>  var hotelName = $(".hotelname").text();
>
>       $(".a").text(hotelName);
> ```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hotelName = $(".hotelname").text();
  
  $(".a").text(hotelName)
  $(".hotelname").hide();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" class="" method="GET" action="http://localhost/blue_bucket/county/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h2 class="a"></h2>
  <?php
    foreach ($query as $row) 
    {   
        ?>
    <h3 class="hotelname">My hotel</h3>

    <div class="book-it-btn">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```